# apache dbcp maxidle

Tags: apache-commons-dbcp

The maxIdle property of Apache DBCP is described as :

"The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit. "

can someone explain what does "without extra ones being released" mean.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here "extra ones" means the connections that are NOT active

Comment: use comment next time please if the question is not so formative and good.

Comment: @AhmedEkri i am new here, so cannot add comment, but I find his question not too bad - the official dbcp doc. describes maxIdle in a confusing way